# Exe standard output writing in chunks, not immediately - Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++

I have an exe (VC++ Application), which runs all through the day, prints logs then and there using printf() and Console::WriteLine(); statements.

This exe is called by a batch script as below

```
**************
set log=D:\MyProj\log\MyProg.log
CMD /C D:\MyProj\MyProg.exe>>%log% 2>&1
echo %date% %time% End >>%log%
**************
```

But here log file is not updating in real time. Log is updating in chunks or at the completion of exe process. So I am not able to track what is going on in real time.

Some times I could even see log traces coming from previous execution[Not sure].

I am clueless, what is happening. Guys help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance
Regards
Deepan

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to add logging as part of the actual executable?

Comment: Yes, as a quick solution, we are planning for like what you said. 
To write it to another log. But that exe is kinda legacy with high impact. My client wont allow to modify it easily, unless convinced. But I just want to know why batch script printing outputs in chunks.

Comment: [Found the cause] : printf() is the culprit. It is not flushing the output immediately. So I suggested the stackholders to change all the printfs to either Console:WirteLine() or printing to another log file.

Comment: `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)` will remove buffering from `stdout`.